# Thinkpad T460p WLAN problems

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, thinkpad

Sometimes my WLAN works, sometimes it doesn't show any networks (although there are many; I can see it with my phone). Rebooting helps. I have an **Intel Wireless 8260 chip**. I use the proprietary driver, as not using it didn't work at all.

What is the issue and how can I fix it?

### Debug output

Chip gets recognized:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network                    
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 44:85:00:74:18:41
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:128 memory:f2100000-f2101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 50:7b:9d:e2:0c:93
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:125 memory:f2200000-f221ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enxe20c6546aca7
       serial: e2:0c:65:46:ac:a7
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.112 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Driver seems to be loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep wifi
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

iwconfig shows it, too. It is not disabled by the function keys, as `Tx-Power=0 dBm` and not `Tx-Power=off`:

```
$ sudo iwconfig
enxe20c6546aca7  no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

Dmesg when it didn't work:

```
dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp
[    4.033651] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.033666] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.033804] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.056273] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.098668] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    4.098977] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.099898] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.100833] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.246808] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.247687] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.510635] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    4.510968] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.511344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.512637] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.651268] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.652059] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.652926] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.739438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
```

dmesg when it worked:

```
$ dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp
[    4.002403] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.002418] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.003545] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.019494] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.068569] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[    4.068879] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.069859] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.072034] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.218682] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.219874] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.620410] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    4.620953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.621328] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.621998] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.760365] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.760788] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.761451] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: can't access the RSA semaphore it is write protected
[    4.852426] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    5.174281] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[   20.399706] wlp3s0: authenticate with 00:1f:3f:10:85:c7
[   20.408384] wlp3s0: send auth to 00:1f:3f:10:85:c7 (try 1/3)
[   20.415065] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   20.417192] wlp3s0: associate with 00:1f:3f:10:85:c7 (try 1/3)
[   20.428684] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 00:1f:3f:10:85:c7 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   20.430381] wlp3s0: associated
[   20.430426] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: When it does *NOT* show networks, is there any clue here? `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp`

Comment: @chili555 I don't know. I've just added the output. `wlp3s0: link is not ready` does not look good to me, but I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While chili555's answer is very good, and will remove those nasty errors, you could also try this:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

If this works, you can create a script to automate it.

Open a terminal and type the following:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service` Now paste the script in there with a right click. Exit with CTRL + X and press Y to save. Now to activate it: `sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service`

Script:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Hope this helps. It works on my laptop. (Intel 7265)

Comment: I don't know why, but this solved the issue. Thank you :-)

Comment: You are very welcome. I have this issue myself, really hope it will be fixed soon. But luckily this fixes it until then.

Answer (score 3):

Your driver loads the -16 firmware when later firmware files have been released and are available. With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-8000C*  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Actually, clone from https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git this has even more recent firmwares; up to 19.313137.0, in `iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode` which is the latest that the ubuntu driver supports.
Also, no need to reboot. You just need to do `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` to reload the driver with proper firmware

Comment: @Treviño Why the `iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode`? Why not `iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode` (which has the highest number) or any of the other 9 `iwlwifi-8000C-*.ucode` files?

Comment: The driver is hard-coded to look for the highest it can use and, if it is not found, the next-highest, etc., until it finds usable firmware. It appears, from your `dmesg` that the version of iwlwifi built in to your kernel is written to start with -19 and work down. If better firmware does not resolve your problem, we will try a few other things.

Comment: @MartinThoma the driver shipped with Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support that revision... It supports only firwmare up to rev 19.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. I could see with `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` that `iwlwifi-8000C-19` was loaded, but the link didn't become ready.

Comment: Now I'm currenlty not using the proprietary driver and it works.

Comment: If you are referring to the proprietary driver that is installed by the *Additional Drivers* tool, it is for Broadcom devices and I suspect that it would interfere.